# VoucherList and SubscriberList put together?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

i have a list with special VoucherCodes which look like below:

```
VoucherCode | VoucherStatus | VoucherDate | Subscriber
Code0000001 |     false     |             |
Code0000002 |     false     |             |
Code0000003 |     false     |             |
Code0000004 |     false     |             |
```

And on the other hand i have a list of subscribers.

What i want: After i send my Newsletter i want automaticly use a VoucherCode of my VoucherList and set the Status to "true". Furthermore i want to see the date and the Subscriber which get the code.

```
VoucherCode | VoucherStatus | VoucherDate | Subscriber
Code0000001 |     true      |  14.09.2015 | email1@example.de
Code0000002 |     true      |  14.09.2015 | email1@example.de
Code0000003 |     false     |             |
Code0000004 |     false     |             |
```

Would that be able?

Comment: do you have a piece of code that you tried ?

Comment: List or data extension?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the list you are mentioning is actually a Data Extension, you should be able to use this code:

```
%%[
    set @CouponRow = ClaimRow("VoucherDataExtensionName", "VoucherStatus", "VoucherDate", Now(), "Subscriber", _SubscriberKey) 
    if Empty(@CouponRow) then ]%%
]%%

No coupons available. Might want to do someting here like use RaiseError() to stop the email and log the info to a DE. Send a notification etc... 

%%[ else ]%%

Your Coupon Code is %%=Field(@CouponRow,"CouponCode")=%%

%%[ endif ]%%
```

Note:

- You will need to change `VoucherDataExtensionName` to the name of the DE that is actually holding your vouchers.
- If you do not have SubscriberKey enabled, you will need to change `_SubscriberKey` to `EmailAddr`

In the documentation for SFMC, the **ClaimRow** function is described in detail and even contains the recommended Data Extension layout that you should use. You might consider adding fields like Job ID, Subscriber ID, etc. In general its a good practice to log as much information as you might need down the road to trouble shoot any issues.

I suggest you read the documentation here before proceeding: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/data_extension_ampscript_functions/#section_4